# Launching a program with /sbin/runscript into /etc/init.d without creating a orphaned process

Tags: linux, shell-script, openrc

I've a script into `/etc/init.d` that executes a process. This is an OpenRC `/sbin/runscript`, but it starts a process becomes orphaned. In fact, when I do the command:

```
ps -elf | awk '{if ($5 == 1){print $4" "$5" "$15}}'
```

I see this orphan process with ppid 1. In other words, how can I avoid to create a orphaned process into a `/sbin/runscript`? With normal script I can put `wait` after command to run process and `&` at the end of the command to launch the script. But how may I do it with boot scripts?

The contents of the init script are

```
start() { 
    ebegin "Starting ${RC_SVCNAME}" 
    start-stop-daemon --start --background --chdir "${HWBR_HOME}/Myscript" --exec "java" --make-pidfile --pidfile "${HWBR_MYSCRIPT_PIDFILE}" --stdout /dev/null -- -jar Myprocess.jar 
    rv=$? 
    eend $rv 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your script so we can see exactly what you're doing?

Comment: start() {
        ebegin "Starting ${RC_SVCNAME}"
        start-stop-daemon --start --background --chdir "${HWBR_HOME}/Myscript" --exec "java" --make-pidfile --pidfile "${HWBR_MYSCRIPT_PIDFILE}" --stdout /dev/null -- -jar Myprocess.jar
        rv=$?
        eend $rv
}